# Use node.js to idle games on a webserver?

Tags: node.js, webserver, node.js-stream

**I have no experience with programming (*besides making simple HTML contact information websites*) so I want to know if an idea I have is possible.**

An article caught my eye where someone was using a [Raspberry Pi running node.js](http://geek-mag.com/posts/255106/) to idle Steam games and would like to know if doing such a thing were possible using a webserver instead of a running computer?

I would like to do this because leaving a computer running 24/7 just to get hours played/card drops in a video game is an unnecessary expense and I have space on a server I'm not currently using.

My questions are;

> How/Is it possible?
>
> Is this code still usable?
>
> How much resource/power could this actually take from the server itself?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. There are a smarter way though.

By using the steam api, you can modify your current game id. Goes under the term "appid".

Your idea was made long ago, everyone uses the program Steam Idle Master for the task:
https://github.com/jshackles/idle_master

Comment: They use Steam Idle Master to have it running on their computer not a webserver right? I want a server to run the idle for me.